# Find hidden Postgres tables

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm pretty new to postgres and I know that a `\dt` will show up the tables, `dtIs` will show tables and indexes but I'm looking for how to show/find hidden tables if any?

Answer (score 3):

To find **tables** in *any* schema of a database, you could check the catalog table [`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-class.html)

```
SELECT oid::regclass AS table_name
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  relname = 'my_table_name'
AND    relkind = 'r';
```

Note, this includes "invisible" tables, that are not in your [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777), and even temporary tables from other sessions that you *cannot access at all*. There are no other "hidden" tables.

Tables in *other databases* of the same cluster are *not* included.